# Why does the news reporter not say anything about the lady in “Don't Breathe”?

Tags: plot-explanation, dont-breathe

In the last scene of **Don't Breathe**, the News Reporter on TV says Police has found two bodies of thieves but she has not referred to that lady who is having child of that old Retired man?

Has the Blind Man hidden that body before police arrived at his home?

Comment: @close-voters Is this still "unclear what you're asking"? If not, feel free to retract your close-vote, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

He buried her in a cement pool on the ground.

He then either hid all other proofs, or just locked the basement and didn't allow cops in there. Both the girl thief and the blind man walked away free.

Comment: But is it really possible police don't investigate in house and does'nt found body of that girl or any evidence.

Comment: The police were probably worried about him, and he told them the robbers were taken care of. The law had no probable cause to go investigate the basement, so I'd say its not unlikely to happen.

Comment: Dead people is probable cause, even if it is suspected they were killed in self defense.